# Best timing method?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write an SSH version of ICMP Ping, as follows:

```
TARGET_IP=""  
count=0  
time_start=0  
time_end=0  
time_taken=0  
TARGET_IP=$1  
while [ $count -lt 5 ]
do  
    ((count=count+1))  
    time_start=$(date +%s%N)  
    temp_target_key=$(ssh-keyscan $TARGET_IP) > /dev/null 2>&1  
    time_end=$(date +%s%N)  
    time_taken=$((( $time_end - $time_start ) / 1000000))  
    echo "Time taken=$time_taken ms."  
    target_key=$(echo $temp_target_key | awk '{print $3}') > /dev/null 2>&1  
    echo $temp_target_key > target_key.txt  
    ssh-keygen -l -f target_key.txt > /dev/null 2>&1  
    test=$?  
    if [ $test -ne 0 ]  
    then  
        echo "Device returned invalid RSA Public Key"  
        echo -e "\n"  
        echo -e "\n"  
    else  
        echo "Device responding correctly."  
        echo -e "\n"  
    fi  
done  
exit
```

ICMP Ping reports ping times of 5ms compared to this script reporting 300ms for the same device. I realise that I'm timing the script AND device programming/firmware response times too, but am I doing this the best way please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a better method to simulate a ssh ping. Nevertheless I've tried to improve your script in a more pure bash style:

```
#! /bin/bash

if (($# != 1)); then
    echo "Usage: ${0##*/} host" >&2
    exit 1
fi
TARGET_IP="$1"

target_key_file="target_key.txt"

for ((count=0; count < 5; count++))
do
    time_start=$(date +%s%N)  
    temp_target_key=$(ssh-keyscan "$TARGET_IP") > /dev/null 2>&1  
    time_end=$(date +%s%N)  
    time_taken=$(((time_end - time_start ) / 1000000))  
    echo "Time taken=$time_taken ms."

    read _ _ target_key _ <<< "$temp_target_key"
    echo "$target_key"

    echo "$temp_target_key" >| "$target_key_file" 
    if ! ssh-keygen -l -f "$target_key_file" > /dev/null 2>&1  
    then echo -e "Device returned invalid RSA Public Key.\n\n"  
    else echo -e "Device responding correctly.\n\n"
    fi  
done
```

Comment: Thanks. My scripting is amatuer at best as it's not my main job. All improvement/education welcome.